# 0x80040e51 Description: "Provider cannot derive parameter information and SetParameterInfo has not been called."

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am trying to execute a query against oracle with the where clause including

```
BETWEEN date AND date2
```

First round of research shows that the oracle OLEDB provider does not allow for parameterized queries, and these should be set in variables.  So I have created 3 variables.  2 to hold my dates that are populated correctly, and one to hold the query with the expression ending in:

```
 BETWEEN to_date('" + (DT_WSTR, 30)@[User::lastRun]  + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AND to_date('" + (DT_WSTR, 30) @[User::thisRun] + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')"
```

When I click "Evaluate Expression" in the expression builder, it evaluates correctly to

```
BETWEEN to_date('1/1/1900','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AND
to_date('1/1/2010','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

And I am able to run this against oracle successfully using other tools.

But when I try to run the package, I receive:

> [mySource [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PjKy.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E51. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E51  Description:
>   "Provider cannot derive parameter information and SetParameterInfo has
>   not been called.".

Where mySource is the OLE DB Source.  It has it's AccessMode set to "SQL Command From Variable" and SQLCommandVariable set to my query variable.

I also tried manually setting all of the Output external columns, and changing some of the values I was selecting in the query to cast away the oracle DATE datatype:

```
to_char(PT.CREATED_DTTM,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

I'm still pretty new to SSIS, so I am not even sure I am looking in the correct place for the root of this error.  Anyone have ideas where to go from here?

Screenshots as requested.  As you can see the "from variable" query works as expected in preview mode, but when I try to execute it I get the error.

[image: Control Flow]
[image: Data Source]
[image: Debug error]

Comment: Yes, the first 2 are populated by execute SQL Tasks. As I showed the variable evaluates correctly (but with default values of the first two date variables) "When I click 'Evaluate Expression' in the expression builder, it evaluates correctly to"

Comment: I'll add screenshots tomorrow when I am back in front of that computer.  For now, I can say that the preview does show that the query executes correctly-- the problem has something to do with the adding it to OLEDB source.

Comment: Added screenshots as requested. I'm only mapping a single Output Column for now until this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting this in the "expressions" on the DataFlow, and NOT on the OLD DB source, making sure the variable still has "EvaluateAsExpression" = True.

You can also see that I have updated from OLE DB to using the [Attunity Oracle connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470675%28SQL.100%29.aspx).

[image: DataFlowSource]

Comment: Hi, if you are setting expression for [Oracle Source].[SqlCommand] at Data Flow, then what to set in "Oracle Source" inside the Data Flow task? How do i get the output columns and perform transformations?